# how link row in tableView to a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have two viewControllers, ViewController and TableViewController. the ViewController has a button, when pressed the TableViewController will start. the TableViewContoller contains 5 rows.

what I am trying to do is, when I press only the even rows I should go back to ViewController. To solve this problem, we can use unwindSegue, but I do not know how to have the segue respond to the even rows in the table.

please let me know how to make a row in the table linked to the segue

below is the code for TableViewController

**code**:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@property NSArray *tableData;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Android",
                  @"iOS",
                  @"swift",
                  @"objective-c",
                  @"openCV",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  
(NSInteger)section {

return [self.tableData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]   
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  
reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];

return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: 
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"%li", indexPath.row);
NSLog(@"%@", [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

}

 @end
```

Comment: you can call performSegueWithIdentifier in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @ReinierMelian but I can't link the tableview to the exit icon to create an unwindsegue

Comment: make the segue between your ViewController and your destinationViewController and put an identifier

Comment: you don't even need unwind segue, you can just pop back or dismiss the current controller!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri would you please provide code how to do it

Comment: How did you present tableview from initial view controller ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri using a segue

Comment: if you present the controller, then dismiss it, if you push the controller then you can call popViewController on even row selection!

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: 
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
         // Even row...
    }

}
```